# Motor and Ethernet shields together

Tags: arduino

I was wondering if it is possible to plug a motor shield on top of an Ethernet shield, even though the direction pins on the motor shield would be connected to the same pins as the spi bus.  I was thinking that it would work if, in the coding, I disabled both chip selects on the Ethernet shield before I used the motors.

Comment: [This answer to a different Arduino question](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/816/350) might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of the chipselect pin is so that multiple devices (in this case, shields) can share the same SPI bus.

As long as no two chipselect pins are the same, you ought to be fine. Make sure only one chip select pin is on at any given time.